# Integrating WPF and Windows Forms Projects in one Solution

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, visual-studio

I have a big Windows Form Application which works as a machine configuration software and that interacts with the user, collects the data from the machine and operates on a SQL Database with 15 sub projects associated with it. It was developed with a singleton pattern long back.

Additionally I have a WPF Application developed recently with MVVM which is used to interact with the Database with a back-end project to get data from the database and display meaningful results to the user.

Now, I would like to know, if it is a good programming practice to combine both WPF and Windows Forms Projects under one solution. Will it result in longer loading and build times ?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 currently.

Comment: Although it is a primarily opinion based question, there's no harm in having one solution.

Comment: As more you load, more time you need to compile everything. Regarding speed, there have been many improvements to Visual Studio's loading time of large solutions recently. Take a quick look at this blog from Microsoft: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/04/04/load-solutions-faster-with-visual-studio-2017-version-15-6/

Comment: @TanveerBadar Thanks for pointing it out that it is opinion based.

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp The blog is an interesting read. Based on the opinions, I see the integration of WPF and WinForms is not a bad idea at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I would like to know, if it is a good programming practice to combine both WPF and Windows Forms Projects under one solution. Will it result in longer loading and build times ?

It's common to have several different projects, including several different client applications, in the same Visual Studio solution. You may still deploy each executable separately.

Obviously the total build and load time will increase (at least in theory) for each project that you add to the solution but this shouldn't be an issue considering that you only need to re-build projects that have actually changed since the last build during development.

To answer your question, it's not considered a bad practice to have several client application projects in the same solution.

You may also have several solution files, e.g. one solution that contains all projects and a WPF solution that only contains projects that the WPF application uses and so on. This is what I usually do when the solution consists of 100+ projects.